# Konva addEventListener click to multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

Hey all I am wanting to add a listener to my canvas in order to see which image is clicked on by the user.

Currently I have the following code (and it works just fine):

```
theImg.on('click', function(evt) {
    console.log(this.id());
    console.log('X: ' + this.x());
    console.log('Y: ' + this.y());
});
```

However, if I have more than just one image on it then I do not want to have to create a **zzzz.on('click',...** for *each* image on there.

I noticed that Konva has a addEventListener so I've tried that doing the below:

```
document.getElementById('theImg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.id());
  console.log('X: ' + this.x());
  console.log('Y: ' + this.y());
}, false);
```

And it seems not to work even with calling a specific image? I get an error when trying this in my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/8jv02mL3/9/):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

So besides the error I get, how also can I set up the **addEventListener** in order to fire off whenever I click on the images only?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `document.getElementById('theImg')` as this function search in document object model, not in virtual Konva objects. Your `Konva.Image` is not part of DOM.

`addEventListener` is just alias for `on` method.

To solve you tasks you can use event bubbling. You may listen `click` on whole stage:

```
stage.on('click', function(e) {
    var node = e.target;
    var isImage = (node.className === 'Image'); 
    if (isImage) {
        console.log(node.id());
        console.log('X: ' + node.x());
        console.log('Y: ' + node.y());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8jv02mL3/10/